# Typeahead remote object from node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typeahead.js, typeahead, twitter-typeahead

I have a huge problem with this. I want to use Twitter Typeahead autocomplete with node.js.

User select name and get all data about him from database (name, address, mail).

I've tried to pass object (data), but I get "undefined" (screen 1). If I pass (data.name) it's ok but then I can't access to another values (address, mail..)

Please give me a hint how to connect this, or how to pass object and in typeahead input get just name?

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input.typeahead').typeahead({
            name: 'name',
            remote:{
                url:  "https://testtest.com/customers/wybierz/search?key=%QUERY",
            },      
            limit: 100
        }).on('typeahead:selected', function (event, selection) {
    $('.profile_add_new').show();
    $('#profil0').text(selection.name); 
    $('#profil1').text(selection.address);  
    $('#profil2').text(selection.email);    
    });   
    });
    </script>
```

node.js

```
app.get('/customers/wybierz/search', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
req.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
connection.query('SELECT * FROM pacjenci WHERE name LIKE "%'+req.query.key+'%"', function(err, rows, fields) {
          if (err)
              console.log("Error inserting : %s ",err );

            for(i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
                {
                 data.push(rows[i]);
                }    
            res.end(JSON.stringify(data));

        });           
    });
});
```

[image: http://i.imgur.com/bNzFZTz.png]

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: @Amit typeahead.js 0.9.3

Comment: That's more then 2 years old, and if I'm not mistaken API has changed dramatically (for example, usage of Bloodhound). I suggest you first update your library, migrate your code, then ask again if you still have problems.

Comment: @Amit but there is no problem with version, I want to figure out how to pass object to typeahead

Comment: It's harder to help with obsolete code. documentation isn't there, reproducing is harder, relevant information is more up to date...

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare an array called as data. Try this,

```
app.get('/customers/wybierz/search', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
req.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
connection.query('SELECT * FROM pacjenci WHERE name LIKE "%'+req.query.key+'%"', function(err, rows, fields) {
      if (err)
          console.log("Error inserting : %s ",err );
        var data = [];
        for(i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
            {
             data.push(rows[i]);
            }    
        res.end(JSON.stringify(data));

    });           
  });
});
```